# How to create a string with 2 levels of single quote in javascript?

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure, quote

I'm writing a procedure in snowflake- which in javascript language.
now I need to call a procedure which his parameter is a query,
while my query has quotes in it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MNG.DQA.SP_DQA_CREATE_LOG_REPORT()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS $$
var str = '\\'1234\\', \\'5678\\'';
var MySQLCommand_1 = `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE X IN ${str}`;
var MySQLCommand_2 = `CALL MY_PROCEDURE('${MySQLCommand_1}');
```

now, until MySQLCommand_1 everything is just fine.
but when I'm trying to call the procedure- MySQLCommand_2 is trying to be with 3 single quotes!
one in MySQLCommand_1, and another one for MY_PROCEDURE parameter which should be VARCHAR type.

anybody could help please?

Comment: Your MySQLCommand_2 is missing the closing backtick ` in the example code

Comment: Additionally, you can use double and single quotes whinin the same string. Have you tried that?

Comment: @ckoala the missed ` is my wrong, ignore this. I tries double quotes- did not help, cause snowflake.execute statement is need to be in snowflake syntax- and snowflake does not use double qoutes to surround a string

Answer (score 1):

```js
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_DQA_CREATE_LOG_REPORT()
RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
COMMENT = '
Proc Name : SP_DQA_CREATE_LOG_REPORT
Proc Description : 
Author: Sriganesh Palani
'
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
    var i_value = '''1234'', ''5678''';
    
    var MySQLCommand_1 = `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE X IN (` + i_value + `)`;
    
    var stmt_MySQLCommand_1 = snowflake.createStatement(
        {
            sqlText: 'MySQLCommand_1'
        }
    );
    
    try{
        var MySQLCommand_1_result = stmt_MySQLCommand_1.execute();
        
        while(MySQLCommand_1_result.next()){
            
            sp_input = MySQLCommand_1_result.getColumnValue(1);
            
            var stmt_MySQLCommand_2 = snowflake.createStatement(
            {
                sqlText: 'CALL MY_PROCEDURE(:1)',
                binds: [sp_input]
            });
            
            // Snowflake statement execution part
            try{
                var result = stmt_MySQLCommand_2.execute();
                return 'success';
            }
            
            // Exception handling part
            catch(err){
                return "Error @ line 40:" + err;
            }   
        }
        
    }
    
    // Exception handling part
    catch(err){
        return "Error @ line 49:" + err;
    }
$$;
```

I haven't tested the code, change the code based on your requirement